# Dual Boot ubuntu with Windows 10 - using one of two internal hard drives

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I wasn't exactly sure what to call the title. I want to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 10.

I just bought a new laptop that has both a 512GB SSD and 2TB HDD internally. The SSD is used to store Operating Systems and programs, and the HDD will be used for regular files. I want to have ubuntu running alongside Windows 10 before I install any files on the HDD.

Is there a way to format the HDD so that i can burn the .ISO file so I don't have to use a USB (The laptop doesn't have an optical drive so can't use CD)?

I tried Unetbootin but got errors when choosing that option after i restarted the computer and got the option to choose OS.

I mainly need help formatting the HDD so i can install ubuntu on the SSD. Once I have that, I know how to finish installing Ubunutu.

Answer (score 0):

If the HDD is really empty, you can just use dd to copy the Ubuntu ISO to the drive, wasting most of the 2T space, and boot it to install to the SDD.  Afterwards you can simply repartition the HDD and do something else with the drive when ready.  Most of the tools for burning ISOs go to some lengths to prevent writing onto a hard disk, for fear you are making an error.